# бар-чарт таблица на Python

Tags: python

Существует ли библиотека в Python, с помощью которой можно делать такие графики?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**

```
print(frame)

                          Страна  Количество пользователей
0                         Россия                        78
1                         Латвия                         1
2                       Беларусь                         3
3  Объединенные Арабские Эмираты                         1
4                          Нигер                         1
5                        Украина                         3
6                           Кипр                         1
7                        Молдова                         1
```

Пытаюсь построить график:

```
sns.barplot(x='Страна', y='Пользователи', data=frame)
plt.title('Количество пользователей')
plt.show()
```

Но вылезает ошибка из-за x='Страна', y='Пользователи':

```
    raise ValueError(err)
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Пользователи'
```

Comment: Смотрели в matplotlib? Еще можно в PyQt5 посмотреть

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bmatplotlib%5D+bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удобно использовать `Seaborn`, если данные у вас загружены в `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Страна': ['Россия', 'США', 'Нарния', 'Средиземье'],
     'Пользователи': [100, 200, 150, 45]})
sns.barplot(x='Страна', y='Пользователи', data=df);
plt.title('Количество пользователей');
```

[image: users]